# Convert cell to numeric array OR properly read file with spaces as delimiter

Tags: matlab, file, delimiter, space

I have a .txt file that has an matrix in it, as delimiters it uses spaces and I can't change the format of the file.

It looks something like this:

```
    2    1    5 -0.92765441D+00  0.00000000D+00
    3    1    5  0.36786029D+00  0.00000000D+00
   14    1   -7  0.64312576D-01  0.00000000D+00
    1    2    7  0.64312576D-01  0.22737368D-12
   12    2   -5  0.36786029D+00  0.22737368D-12
```

**What I actually want to do:**

Import that data somehow, and store it in an 34x5 matrix.

**What is happening?**

Currently I'm using importdata(), but that stores the data in a n*1 cell vector, like this:

```
'    2    1    5 -0.92765441D+00  0.00000000D+00'
'    3    1    5  0.36786029D+00  0.00000000D+00'
'   14    1   -7  0.64312576D-01  0.00000000D+00'
'    1    2    7  0.64312576D-01  0.22737368D-12'
'   12    2   -5  0.36786029D+00  0.22737368D-12'
```

Is there any way to get that coverted into a matrix, or another way to read that output.txt?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to do with the D? It doesn't fit in a numeric array.

Comment: The character `D` is used instead of `E` in scientific notation for double precision number by some Fortran programs (and may be other). It is not widely recognized however, and totally not supported by Matlab. You have to replace all your `D` by `E` first, then you can use any Matlab data import function.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the primary reason for the failed import is that your file uses the character `'D'` to indicate scientific notation which isn't supported natively by MATLAB. Instead, you'll want to replace that with `'E'` or `'e'` so that MATLAB knows how to handle the last two columns properly.

Rather than using `importdata`, you can read in the entire file as a string with `fread` and then use `textread` (or any other data import function) to actually convert it into numbers.

```
% Read in the file contents as a string
fid = fopen(filename, 'rb');
stringData = fread(fid, '*char')';
fclose(fid) 

% Replace 'D' with 'e' to be able to parse scientific notation properly
stringData = strrep(stringData, 'D', 'e');

% Convert this string to a numeric array
data = textscan(stringData, '%f');
data = reshape(data{1}, 5, []).';

%   2.0000    1.0000    5.0000   -0.9277         0
%   3.0000    1.0000    5.0000    0.3679         0
%   14.0000   1.0000   -7.0000    0.0643         0
%   1.0000    2.0000    7.0000    0.0643    0.0000
%   12.0000   2.0000   -5.0000    0.3679    0.0000
```

Comment: At least someone spotted that `D` is not a valid scientific notation character in Matlab. You should use [`str2double`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) instead of `str2num` which is going to be deprecated (_and uses `eval` internally ... bweeah_).

Comment: @Hoki That's a good point. Unfortunately `str2double` can't parse multiple numbers like that, but I went ahead and swapped it out for `textread`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `readtable`?

From the help [files](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html), there is an option to specify the delimiter.

```
T = readtable('mySpaceDelimTable.txt','Delimiter',' ','ReadVariableNames',false)
```

Afterwards you can use an `table2array` to convert items back to a matrix if you so choose.

*EDIT* Have you tried to use the delimiter for importdata as well?

```
A = importdata(___,delimiterIn)
```